# separar campo SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla con los siguientes datos

```
select * from archivo_final

    cs_promocion      3
d_promocion       DSCTO NESPRESSO
st_promocion      A
fecha_desde       2017-07-04
fecha_hasta       2017-12-31
almacenes         109,111,113,114,117,118,120,121,124,126,128,130,132,134,135,1
                  38,140,141,143,144
d_definicion      Al comprar un minimo de
cn_comprar        1
grupo_definicion  3
nombre            NESPRESSO
inclu_definicion  plano sku:6164,6165,6170,6177,6178,8636,8637,8638,13010,13011

inclu_descuento
exclu_definicion
exclu_descuento
act_definicion    1
act_descuento
```

con la información que esta en el campo inclu_definicion, debo de realizar un join con otra tabla para sacar otra información.

el problema es que en este registro esta guardado como una cadena, existe alguna forma de poder separar cada sku en un campo diferente

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a usar Split
Ejemplo:

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ');
```

Esto de generará una tabla con cada elemento según tu separador.
En este caso:

```
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
.....
```